# Not enough Taxonomist Badges

Tags: support, badges, taxonomist-badge

The Tag page, [Popular view](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags) shows @ 116 Tags with other 50 instances, but the [Taxonomist badge page](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/badges/11/taxonomist) only shows 72 Taxonomist Badges.  What happened to the other 44?

Comment: Can the badge be awarded more than once?  If not, then that could be the problem. (Someone creating more than one tag)

Comment: There may have been special "seed" tags, too.

Comment: @jinguy, well, that could be it.

Comment: @jjnguy, Taxonomist cannot be awarded multiple times.

Comment: @jjnguy, no, quite the opposite, that _is_ the explanation. Or at least, it must contribute. If I create two tags that each get used 50 times, I'll only get one Taxonomist badge.

Comment: @jjnguy, no I think that's it.  When you would get a second badge it just doesn't award it, thereby creating holes.  They should find a way to have the Taxonomist page display them all in a group per user.   You might want to make an answer out of your comment, but I hope that a mod chimes in and lets us know for sure.

Comment: @Pop @Lance, yeah, duh.  That is what I was getting at in my first comment....duh.  I confused myself somehow.

Comment: Lance and @jjnguy, someone resurrected this topic [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114220/131713).

Comment: duplicate of [List of all badges with full descriptions](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67397/list-of-all-badges-with-full-descriptions)

Comment: This isn't even close to being a duplicate.  It's about a displaying discrepancy.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Can the badge be awarded more than once? If not, then that could be the problem.

Someone could create more than one tag eligible for taxonomist, and then there would be holes in the Taxonomist badges.