# can the taxonomist badge be awarded only once?

Tags: support, badges, taxonomist-badge

[This question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/40/can-the-taxonomist-badge-be-awarded-more-than-once) tells the contrary, information [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67397/list-of-all-badges-with-full-descriptions/68258#68258) and [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/badges/11/taxonomist) (no "this badge can be won multiple times" message) suggests it can be awarded only once. Which information is true? I suppose the answer to first question I cited is wrong, maybe it should be corrected somehow.

Comment: Current the Taxonomist badge is *not* awarded multiple times.  The answer is over 2 years old, so I'll clarify what the current intent is when Jeff gets back from vacation.

Comment: @NickCraver Is Jeff back from vacation yet?